Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs/operators' while running npm installed package
I have written a typescript tool and published the package to an artifactory. When I install the package like npm install -g @org/my-tool@1.1.2
The package is installed successfully but when I try to run it like my-tool -v from the terminal, I get the following error:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1251
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs/operators'
Require stack:

The same steps when I do it on a windows machine, everything works.
I tried the following:

Ran the steps on different versions of the node.
npm cache clean --force
Reinstalled node
Cleared node_modules
Rebuilt the package

Nothing worked. Is there anything specific I should try to fix this?

Please add more information like peer dependencies and maybe a small snippet of how your library is being bundled

no peer dependencies.
It is bundled using webpack

set legacy-peer-deps=false in the .npmrc file before building and publishing

Appreciate it's not in the "peerDependencies" and probably a stupid question (maybe good for posterity), but do you have rxjs as a "dependency" in your package.json at all, by any chance (and then rebuild and reinstall your package, of course)?
